# Last value grouped by month for reporting monthly progress

Tags: sql, postgresql, reporting

Hi I have a table that looks like the following

| grouping_coulmn | value | date_modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2020-10-15 |
| 1 | 10 | 2020-10-20 |
| 2 | 3 | 2020-10-20 |
| 1 | 11 | 2020-11-30 |
| 1 | 11 | 2020-12-10 |
| 1 | 5 | 2020-12-15 |

How could I make a query that returns the following results

| grouping_column | last_value_of_month | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | OCT 2020 |
| 1 | 11 | NOV 2020 |
| 1 | 5 | DIC 2020 |
| 1 | 5 | JAN 2021 |
| 2 | 3 | OCT 2020 |
| 2 | 3 | NOV 2020 |
| 2 | 3 | DIC 2020 |
| 2 | 3 | JAN 2021 |

In other words it should return the last value of the group each month, from the first entry until the current month. I could work it out if you don't fill the missing months, but I don't know how to work that out.

**NOTE**: this question was asked on January 2021, just for context.

Comment: Could you fix the top table please? :)

Comment: yeah done noticed after publishing

Comment: With current month, would that be "Jan 2021" ?

Comment: yeah sorry my mind is still in 2020 mode, let me correct it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, generate all the months based on the oldest date in the table:

```
with months as (
  select ddate + interval '1 month' as end_date,
         to_char(ddate, 'MON YYYY') as month
    from generate_series(
           date_trunc(
             'month', 
             (select min(date_modified) from table1)
           ), 
           now(),
           interval '1 month'
         ) as gs(ddate)
)
```

Join that back to your data table, and use `distinct on` to limit the result to one record per `(grouping_column, month)`:

```
select distinct on (t.grouping_column, m.end_date)
       t.grouping_column, t.value as last_value_of_month, m.month
  from months m
       join table1 t
         on t.date_modified < m.end_date
 order by t.grouping_column, m.end_date, t.date_modified desc;
```

Result:

```
 grouping_column | last_value_of_month | month   
 --------------: | ------------------: | :-------
               1 |                  10 | OCT 2020
               1 |                  11 | NOV 2020
               1 |                   5 | DEC 2020
               1 |                   5 | JAN 2021
               2 |                   3 | OCT 2020
               2 |                   3 | NOV 2020
               2 |                   3 | DEC 2020
               2 |                   3 | JAN 2021
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e210f52efd4c74b5e2e818d4cae452fa)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not used to think of joins with things other that = sentences, so this really helps a lot.